How can I send 2k REST API messages in batches of 100 every 1min?
I have a data file (.txt and not .csv) with each line representing a REST API payload message. The requirement is to send 2k messages in batches of 100 every minute. Is it possible to do this in Jmeter? If so, how can I design the test ( which timer to use)?
Steps are:

Read 2k records
Chunk those into blocks of 100 then post to Rest API
Wait 1 min and go to step-1

Thanks.
I am trying to find out if it is possible to simulate this situation first.


You can read the records from the file directly in the request using __StringFromFile() function or CSV Data Set Config, if the file is big - go for the CSV Data Set Config.
In order to send 100 requests at exactly the same moment set the number of threads in the Thread Group to 100 and use Synchronizing Timer with the same number.
Use Flow Control Action sampler to introduce pause of 60000 milliseconds


Sorry for me not saying it clearly. I need to submit a POST request, check the response, then this is repeated for 20 POSTs and then wait for 1min and then repeat the same

Thanks, Ivan. I got it working by adding JSR223 timer with a if condition.
